# python csv, delete all commas but the first and last per line

Tags: python, csv

This should be simple but... I have a botched up csv with commas used within fields. Fortunately though, this csv only has three columns and the surplus commas are all in the middle column - so if I would manage to delete all comma but the first and the last in each line, I should be fine. How would I get csv reader to do this?

Comment: isn't it better if you keep the commas and add quotes around middle field?

Comment: if i could make a quote after the first and before the last comma (so i'd have the middle comma all within quotes), that would also be perfect, yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('bad.csv') as f, open('good.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        first, *middle, last = line.split(',')
        fout.write(f'{first},"{",".join(middle)}",{last}')
```

Comment: i still have to understand the magic you are doing there but it sure does work! thanks!! : )

Comment: @user3647558--for explanation look at [Unpacking Operators in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480), especially section on *Other Uses of * Operator*.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you want a pass-through solution that fixes files on-the-fly while reading, without generating "fixed" files, e.g if you want to directly read the data using e.g. `pandas.read_csv(...)`. In that case, you can do this:

```
def fix_commas(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file) as f:
        buf = f.read()
    buf = '\n'.join([re.sub(r',,+', ',', s) for s in buf.splitlines()])
    return io.StringIO(buf)

# and then
df = pd.read_csv(fix_commas(filename), ...)
```

Example:

```
txt = """
first,second,third
a,,b,bbbb
c,,,,,d,,,,,,,e
f,g,h
"""

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)

# now test:
df = pd.read_csv(fix_commas('test.csv'))
```

Result (in `df`):

```
  first second third
0     a      b  bbbb
1     c      d     e
2     f      g     h
```